# isis2 application connecting failed

Tags: multicast, isis2

I develop a replicate application using isis2. It works by connecting two hosts running the application through a router. I tried connecting these two hosts by a ethernet cable end-to-end, but it failed. Following is error exception:

```
MCMD SockSetup failed: error <System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Network subsystem is down
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SetSocketOption (SocketOptionLevel optionLevel, SocketOptionName optionName, System.Object optionValue) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
at Isis.MCMDSocket.MCMDSockSetup (System.Net.IPAddress theIPAddr) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 > MCMD Mapping:
Group [ORACLE]: rate = 0    VirtIPAddr=224.0.19.136, mapped to 224.0.19.136
```

Is it possible to work? Is this connection incompatible with IP multicast?

Comment: You haven't told us much at all about the way your system is configured or even what O/S you are running.  In general, if you ask for help it would be nice to know: Linux or Windows or what?  What are the network interface configuration parameters?  Etc....  There is also extensive Isis2 documentation on precisely how to deal with this issue, on isis2.codeplex.com, and you don't seem to be aware of that -- have you read that part of the isis2 user manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as configured, your system thinks the Ethernet port is not able to support IP multicast. You have two options. One is to fix the configuration (and you would also need to make sure iptables is configured to allow the packets through, or disabled). The other option is to just use the Isis2 options for running via UDP only, or even via TCP only if you are on a platform that disallows UDP communication.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added an IP multicast group address (224.0.0.0/4) to the interface as you said. It works. I think Ethernet interfaces should be enable for IP multicast, otherwise the data isn't able to know where to send the multicast.

Comment: Yes, but Isis2 can't do that; it is just a software library and doesn't have the needed permissions.  You needed to do that by hand, like you just did.  Some administrative actions can only be done through the Linux configuration commands and cannot reasonably be done in a software library linked to end-user code and running under some random person's uid.